# Show worng heading when enter website url on google serach listing

Tags: joomla

When I am entering my webite URL(www.xyz.org) in google search box then website heading is showing wrong please look below image.. This site is developed in joomla..

[image: you can see first list on images it's show wrong heading]

Comment: add meta description to your site and wait for google to crawl it and update it

Answer (score 0):

- Please go to Joomla Administrator
- Please go to this path Site-> Global Configuration ->Metadata Settings
- Add your description about the site from `"Global Site Meta Description "` editbox.

But it was take some times to display in google...

Try it....

Answer (score -1):

Your title tags are correct, so try looking at the site through Google Webmaster Tools to see if you have any malware active.